# Which text-editor egghead.io uses on Redux videos

Tags: javascript, text-editor, redux

Someone can tell me which text-editor they use?

I could not find the app/site name.

[image: egghead.io Text-editor]
Source:
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output), an online editor.